# How can we display, select and add multiple participants at a time in the conversation using Twilio?

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-conversations

Our requirements are:

1. To show all the available users (Not sure whether to call it `Users` or `Participants`in terms of Twilio).
2. To be able to select multiple users.
3. To add multiple users to the group (Maybe, It is `Conversations` in Twilio).

Not exactly, but somewhat similar to the below screenshot:

[image]

I have already gone through:

[Android Conversations SDK](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/conversations/releases/3.0.1/docs/-conversations%20-android%20-s-d-k/com.twilio.conversations/-conversation/index.html#-1332687556%2FFunctions%2F68704080)

But did not find a way to 1. List available users 2. Add multiple participants at a time.

I also found `User Resource` link:

[Read Multiple Conversation User Resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-resource#read-multiple-conversationuser-resources) but not really sure if there is any better way to achieve what we are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While there is a [User object within the Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-resource), the objects are only created after a user in your application connects to a Conversations SDK (that is, you created an access token for them and they then successfully used that access token to connect to the Conversations Service within your application).

I would recommend that you manage your application's users yourself within your app and list them from your own store of them.

There is, as far as I can see, no way to add more than one participant to a conversation at a time. You will need to loop through the users you want to add as participants and add them each individually.